# Retrieving password expiry warning from Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi

I have a system that uses Active Directory to authenticate users. Now I must use the security settings from AD to warn a user that his password will expire in a few days. The period before a password will be expired when the notification is presented to users is defined as described in [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e7429f5-d38d-4744-a986-798748572f3b/ad-password-expiration-notification).
I want to read the value set in "Interactive logon: Prompt user to change password before expiration"
from AD using javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext. I hope this value is remembered in AD but I have no idea how to find it. I was looking in a set of AD attributes but noone seems to match this information. Is it possible to retrieve this value from AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complicated as this setting is not directly held in Active Directory. This is a part of Group Policy (considering it's configured in a policy and not on a local computer), which is held on a network share and linked in Active Directory.

For a simple example, you can get into it like this:

1. Read your intended OU and check for `gPLink` attribute. The value is something like a list of Group Policy objects linked to the selected OU in a priority descending order. Each of the values is something like: `[LDAP://CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=internal,DC=local;0]`. The first part is a GP location, the last part seems to be a flag (2 meaning that the policy is enforced).
2. Read the policy object(s) and check for `gPCFileSysPath` attribute. This is the location where the policy settings are stored. It would be something like `\\internal.local\sysvol\internal.local\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}`.
3. Inspect the file store from point 2. and look for `MACHINE\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit\GptTmpl.inf` file. It's a regular inf/ini file, investigate `[Registry Values]` section to find a line that reads: `MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\PasswordExpiryWarning=4,14`. This `14` is a policy setting (to prompt for password change 14 days before expiry).

Now, the things get complicated to get the actual resultant set of policies. Policies get inherited from parents, meaning that in point 1. you should be checking the intended OU and all its parent OUs together with a domain node itself, evaluate all the `gPLink`s in appropriate order, possibly also taking into consideration their WMI filter, whether they do apply or not, in order to find out what value is in effect.

If your application happens to run on Windows that can be put under the same group policy it might be easier to just read the information from registry, as this will be already applied by the system.

In any case, I would consider to just use some default expiration warning period, given the amount of complexity to get the value from AD (provided that it is defined in group policy at all and not just defaults on computers locally).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I will use some default value because of the complexity of the exact solution.